# knex connection string with docker compose fails to connect postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, knex.js

I am new to docker and knex. I am connecting docker postgresql with knex connection string. But I am getting below error. I am changing db env variables a lot. But still I am getting the same error. Where I am missing.

[image]

**knexfile**

```
module.exports = {
  client: "pg",
  connection: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/apps",
  migrations: {
    directory: "./migrations",
    tableName: "knex_migraation_apps"
  },
}
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.9"
volumes:
  apps-data:

services:
  apps:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      - "APPS_PORT=3001"
  
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_DB=apps"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - apps-data:/var/lib/pgsql/data
  
  pgadmin-compose:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "placeholder@example.com"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "fakepassword123!"
    ports:
      - "16543:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```